# How can I display in JFrame a JButton in a grid formed by squares?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

How can I display a button in a grid formed by squares? I have been trying to do it by my own but seems not to work because the JButton doesn't show in the grid properly.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class panel extends JFrame{
    public panel() {
        super();
        setSize(600,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        /*
         * Grid
         */
        g.drawRect(200,0,0,600);
        g.drawRect(400,0,0,600);
        g.drawRect(0,200,600,0);
        g.drawRect(0,400,600,0);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        Dimension d = new Dimension (100,100);
        JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        b.setPreferredSize(d);

        p.add(b);
        add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use GridLayout and not BorderLayout to have the jbutton appear in a grid form,
-http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_gridlayout.htm

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't thought about it... Thanks!